# Conflicts between multiple versions of conda

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I use miniconda to manage my python environments on Windows 10. Additionally, I use software called [ESRI ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/get-started.htm#:%7E:text=ArcGIS%20Pro%20is%20the%20latest,elements%20of%20the%20user%20interface.) that comes bundled with it's own versions of conda and python that are somewhat modified to work with their software. I must use ESRI's conda to manage environments that interact with this application.

I have this same set up on both my laptop and desktop, and until recently had no issues. However, recently ESRI's conda stopped working on my laptop. Any conda commands (e.g. `conda list`, `conda info --envs`, `conda create -n myenv`, even just `conda` by itself) produce no output whatsoever. At first I suspected that PATH was set incorrectly, but I've check that this is not the case (even calling ERIS's conda.exe with a full path still does not work). I then suspected that the conda.exe file itself was corrupted, but this also is not the case (copied it to my desktop and it works fine there).

I suspect it may have something to do with my separate miniconda installation. It doesn't seem to be an issue of environmental variables being set incorrectly (again checked against the working system), but I'm wondering if there is any possibility that there are Registry entries (perhaps set by my Miniconda install) that could be causing this issue?

Any thoughts on why this might be the case? Or advice on how to proceed with diagnosing the issue?

EDIT:

Per merv's request, my conda environmental variables:

```
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3
CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3
CONDA_PS1_BACKUP=$P$G
```

Clearly these paths are different than normal due to the custom distribution.

To answer your other questions, no other conda commands generate any output whatsoever. As for `activate` I don't have any other environments to try activating (the arcgispro-py3 env you see above is the name of the 'base' env that ships with the software), but `deactivate` seems to work.  Another slight difference to mention is that `conda activate ...`  is not a command in this special conda, you have to just use `activate` by itself which AFAICT calls a shell script.

Comment: I cross-posted a modified version of this to the GIS stackexchange site, if such cross-posting is against the rules please let me know.

Comment: Tough one: seems very opaque right now. Do any Conda commands generate output when adding verbosity flags (e.g., `conda info -vv`)? Do the shell commands work, e.g., `conda activate <env_name>`? Could you share (add to question) the Conda environment variables? I.e., output from `env | grep -e "^CONDA"` (sorry, I don't know Windows equivalent).

Comment: @merv I edited the post to answer some of these questions. I really do not think it is anything to do with environmental variables. As I mentioned above my desktop has essentially the same set up but is still functioning properly. I can compare the environmental variables between the two and see that they are the same.

Comment: Thanks for adding those things. Unfortunately they don't seem to give any more insight. My other guess is that there is something up with the `conda` Python package, which is distinct from the .exe and actually does most of the work. Perhaps try checking the `lib/python*/site-packages/` directory of the env for the `conda` package. Just guessing though.

Comment: Hmmm, no `conda` package in `site-packages` in this environment. This is likely another idiosyncrasy of ESRI's customized conda/python distribution ( I notice that ESRI's conda.exe is >12 Mb, whereas the 'vanilla' conda.exe in my miniconda install is <100 Kb ... perhaps they have wrapped up the functionality of the `conda` package into the .exe). I temporarily solved this issue by removing the 'vanilla' miniconda install from my system. I *should* be able to have both concurrently (works fine on desktop), so I am still trying to diagnose why the two were conflicting

Comment: There is a thing called [`conda-standalone`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/conda-standalone), which generates a standalone `conda.exe` using `pyinstaller`. Maybe that's what they've used. I've actually used these before, but their functionality still has dependence on correctly configured environment and Conda configuration variables.